# Hyperlink or button does not fire inside repeater item template

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, .net-4.5, repeater

I have a repeater and inside item template I have a button and an anchor.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCategoryList" OnItemDataBound="rptCategoryList_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        ....
        <div style="margin-left: 81.6%;">
            <span runat="server" id="spnRegister" clientidmode="static" class="register pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="float: ; margin-right: 40px; margin-top: -150px; background-color: #3697EA">
                    <a href="register.aspx" style="color: white;" target="_self">Register</a>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
        ....
    </ItemTemplate>
```

when this button is clicked it reloads the same page rather going to register.aspx. I used "view page source" and href is set correctly.

I removed the anchore and added a class to button and used jQuery:

```
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg registerSilver" style="float: ; margin-right: 40px; margin-top: -150px; background-color: #3697EA">
            Register
        </button>

$(function () {
    $('.registerSilver').click(function () {debugger
        window.location = 'register.aspx';
    });
});
```

still not working, keeps reloading the same page.

I even tried to add runat="server" to the hyperlink and set its href in repeater's itemdatabound, no luck.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Sounds like your button is set to submit which causing postback instead of redirection. Try adding `type="button"` attribute e.g. `<button type="button" ...><a href="register.aspx" ...>Link Text</a></button>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of `<button>` tag triggers form submit (i.e. `<form runat="server">` in ASPX page), which probably causing postback to same page instead of redirecting to page URL specified in anchor link. Try setting `type="button"` attribute explicitly like example below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="float: ; margin-right: 40px; margin-top: -150px; background-color: #3697EA">
    <a href="register.aspx" style="color: white;" target="_self">Register</a>
</button>
```

Or use [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) function for `click` event handler in jQuery to prevent default submit action of that button:

```
$('.registerSilver').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    window.location = 'register.aspx';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redirect then why you use button instead of that you can just pass button css class to anchor tag and make it look like button like

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCategoryList" OnItemDataBound="rptCategoryList_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        ....
        <div style="margin-left: 81.6%;">
            <span runat="server" id="spnRegister" clientidmode="static" class="register pull-right">                
                    <a href="register.aspx" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="color: white; float: ; margin-right: 40px; margin-top: -150px; background-color: #3697EA" target="_self">Register</a>
            </span>
        </div>
        ....
    </ItemTemplate>
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

You could also replace the html button to an asp one:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-lg registerSilver" PostBackUrl="register.aspx" Text="Register"/>
```

This way you can set the PostBackUrl attribute.